# How to connect to native Selenium on CircleCI

Tags: selenium, intern, circleci

I'm running a suite of functional tests using [Intern](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#what-is-intern) and following their [advice on connecting to local Selenium with Chromedriver](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#local-selenium).

Locally, everything works well, but on CircleCI I'm getting:

`Error: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED`

Does this have to do with how native Selenium is set up on CircleCI? Do I have to run it manually in the background ([as described here](https://circleci.com/docs/background-process)) or is it running by default already and I'm just not connecting to it properly?

Comment: It's not actually running by default. It will start from a command like that. `webdriver-manager update`, then `webdriver-manager start` with `background: true`.... Where to from there is anyones guess, managed to get it to load chrome, but not yet running tests correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to continue using NullTunnel

As in Intern's documentation says

> If you are having trouble starting the server or getting Intern to
>   communicate with it, verify the server is running correctly by going
>   to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status. It should return a JSON
>   response with a status field of 0.

a) Could you see the expected status?

b) Make sure that you have started Selenium by yourself before running `intern-runner`.

c) Some people say that they need to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, maybe you should try it too?

d) A rare case, but maybe you can check too, is your nodejs version. csnover once mentioned about nodejs version here https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial/issues/10#issuecomment-56390886

2. A better way, I think is to use SeleniumTunnel instead. You will not need to care about downloading and running Selenium then.

Comment: It would be great to see a basic working example of intern running on SeleniumTunnel on CircleCI. Do you need to do anything to the circle.yml? What would the minimum "hello world" app look like?